# TDBChart: load legend without loading data

Tags: teechart

I have TDBChart component on a form, with Checkboxes-Legend to toggle series' visiblity. Maximum 5 series could be visible - this is my definition. To speed up the chart I am trying to load from database only the data for visible series.

But in order to have all the possible items in legend I need to define all the series, with defined dataset and field names.

In this case chart nags me with exceptions about absent columns for invisible series.

Is there possible to load a legend separate from chart data?

Comment: Have you tried to assign `DataSource:=nil;` to those series unselected?

Comment: @Yeray: Yes, but it doesn't help. Once series has loaded data, it cat't forget that fact and demands data regardless of DataSource property state.

Comment: You can `Clear` the series data when it has been unselected

Comment: @Yeray: You wrote "on series data". If I do `series.Clear()` it doesn't help. Series still demands data. May be I need to do `series.SomeData.Clear()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, I've created two series connected to a test `DataSource` (*TeeChart Pro Database* shipped with TeeChart).
I'm clearing the series (`Clear`) when inactive and refreshing their data (`CheckDataSource`) when they are reactivated, using the Chart `OnClickLegend` event.
Note I'm showing each series `Count` using `OnAfterDraw` event.

```
uses Series, CandleCh;

var
  Table1, Table2: TTable;
  barSeries: TBarSeries;
  candleSeries: TCandleSeries;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBChart1.View3D:=False;
  DBChart1.Legend.CheckBoxes:=True;
  DBChart1.MarginLeft:=10;

  Table1:=TTable.Create(Self);
  Table1.DatabaseName:='TeeChart Pro Database';
  Table1.TableName:='Employee';

  Table2:=TTable.Create(Self);
  Table2.DatabaseName:='TeeChart Pro Database';
  Table2.TableName:='Stock';

  barSeries:=DBChart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries;
  candleSeries:=DBChart1.AddSeries(TCandleSeries) as TCandleSeries;

  with barSeries do
  begin
    DataSource:=Table1;
    YValues.ValueSource:='SALARY';
    XLabelsSource:='LASTNAME';
    HorizAxis:=aTopAxis;
  end;

  DBChart1.Axes.Top.Grid.Visible:=False;

  with candleSeries do
  begin
    VertAxis:=aRightAxis;
    DataSource:=Table2;
    YValues.ValueSource:='DATE';
    OpenValues.ValueSource:='OPEN';
    HighValues.ValueSource:='HIGH';
    LowValues.ValueSource:='LOW';
    CloseValues.ValueSource:='CLOSE';
  end;

  Table1.Active:=True;
  Table2.Active:=True;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBChart1ClickLegend(Sender: TCustomChart; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var i: Integer;
begin
  if barSeries.Active then
     barSeries.CheckDataSource
  else
     barSeries.Clear;

  if candleSeries.Active then
     candleSeries.CheckDataSource
  else
     candleSeries.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBChart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption:='Bar: ' + IntToStr(barSeries.Count) + ' values, Candle: ' + IntToStr(candleSeries.Count) + ' values';
end;
```